# python Hex string to array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a string

```
s='0xbb06e6cf,0xbb6fceb1,0xbabb39c3'
```

and first I want to convert it to array like

```
arr = [0xbb06e6cf,0xbb6fceb1,0xbabb39c3]
```

and then change the arr to float64 arr, which is the fastest way to convert the hex arr to float64?

Comment: `arr = [int(x, 16) for x in s.split(',')]`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using below code:

```
s='0xbb06e6cf,0xbb6fceb1,0xbabb39c3'
x=s.split(",")
print x
```

Output is:

```
['0xbb06e6cf', '0xbb6fceb1', '0xbabb39c3']
```

Answer (score 0):

First you want to split the string on "," characters. Python implements a `split()` function that does this. Then you would want to convert each string returned from the split function into a number, you can use the `int()` function for this by specifying the base the number is in. Using list comprehension, the following code will do what you want:

```
s='0xbb06e6cf,0xbb6fceb1,0xbabb39c3'
arr = [int(n, base=16) for n in s.split(',')]
```